# VB DBNull not working like book says it should

Tags: vb.net

The book shows the following code and says that the 1st conditional check would be true because strMyString is NOTHING, but when I run the program I get no output to the console.  If I change my first IF statement to IF NOT strMyString is sysNull then I get "Initialize my string" on the console.  The book is for VB 2008 and I am using VB 2013, so is this just because of a version difference? Or is the book a typo?

```
    Dim sysNull As System.DBNull = System.DBNull.Value
    Dim strMyString As String = Nothing

    If strMyString Is sysNull Then
        strMyString = "Initialize my String"
    End If
    If Not IsDBNull(strMyString) Then
        Console.WriteLine(strMyString)
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Nothing and DBNull are not the same thing.  use `If strMyString Is  Nothing Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DBNull` type exists to represent NULL values in a database specifically, hence the "DB" prefix.  It was required because early versions of .NET did not support nullable value types, e.g. assigning `Nothing` to an `Integer` variable gives it the value zero.

If you're working with a database then you can compare any `Object` reference to `DBNull.Value` to see whether you got NULL from the database, e.g. the `Item` property of a `DataRow` or data reader.  You can also assign `DBNull.Value` to the `Item` property of a `DataRow` or `Value` property of a parameter to save NULL to a database.

If you're not working with a database then you should not be using `DBNull` at all.  If you want to test for or assign no object then you use `Nothing` exclusively.  Note that `DBNull.Value` and `Nothing` are completely different things.  `Nothing` is no object at all while `DBNull.Value` is an object of type `DBNull` that represents no value in a database field.

Also, I would suggest not using that `IsDBNull` method carried over from VB6.  Both a `DataRow` and data reader have their own methods for testing for NULL values and otherwise use this:

```
If myField Is DBNull.Value Then
```

If you want to determine whether to save NULL back to a database based on whether an object reference is `Nothing` or not then you can do this:

```
If myObject Is Nothing Then
    myParameter.Value = DBNull.Value
Else
    myParameter.Value = myObject
End If
```

For nullable value types that would look like this:

```
If myNullable.HasValue Then
    myParameter.Value = myNullable.Value
Else
    myParameter.Value = DBNull.Value
End If
```